# How can I access the CFFileServlet directory on a ColdFusion Web Server using multisite.dll?

Tags: coldfusion, windows-xp, iis-5, coldfusion-8

I am using the multisite.dll ISAPI filter (http://www.hairy-spider.com/post/Multisite.aspx) in order to develop on several websites simultaneously on my Windows XP Professional/IIS 5.1 workstation. I am developing both HTML and ColdFusion websites. On the ColdFusion websites, when I use CFIMAGE to create an image in memory - a CAPTCHA image, to be exact - it is not viewable. I know the image is being created in the correct directory - ColdFusion8\tmpCache\CFFileServlet_cf_captcha - and the ColdFusion is generating the correct code to display the image:

```
<img src="/CFFileServlet/_cf_captcha/[file].png" />
```

But I can't get the image to display. I've tried adding a virtual directory to the Default Website in IIS, as well as adding a mapping in the ColdFusion Administrator, but neither helps.

Does anyone have any suggestions that don't include upgrading Windows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need that DLL any more.  IIS 5 can handle host headers natively, unless you've ran into other issues that require you to use it.

Two things:
1.  Try unchecking the 'Verify file exists' setting in IIS.
2. If that doesn't work, does the cfimage  tag work without the DLL installed?

Comment: Here is the KB article on how to set this up without the DLL http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190008 .  If this can't be used and you need to use the DLL, can you comment back why?

Comment: Thanks @David, I will look at the article and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: I added all of the Host Headers, but I can't figure out how to get each site to point to its respective Home Directory. For instance, obviously, "http://localhost/", points to C:/Inetpub/wwwroot. But, I have another site named "mysite" that resides at "C:/mydir/mysite/", and another site name "mysite2" that resides at "C:/mydir/mysite2/". Right now, they all point to "C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/". How do I get each site to point to its respective home directory?

Answer (score 0):

first thing i would do is remove the multisite.dll and just use one site to see if it really is the dll causing the problem or if it is something else.

next... what version of cf is this? are you at the least service pack for your version of ColdFusion?